# How to use async javascript to wait for page load before executing a function on that page

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

From my index.html page, when a user clicks on a link, I want to execute a function, with following signature: updateFlightPage() on another html page called flight.html

However, the updateFlightPage() function is not executing properly, because I suspect it is trying to access an element on the flight.html page before the page has finished loading. I am very new to JS, but I suspect I need to use async JS to circumvent this problem.

How would I use promises or ASYNC AWAIT to fix this?

Please see my code below:

This function is called on my index.html page:

```
const updateFlightNum = function(e) {
        if (e.target.nodeName === 'A') {
            UIController.updateFlightPage(e.target.innerText);
        }
}
```

Here is the udateFlightPage(){} function that is called in previous function:

```
updateFlightPage: function(flightNum) {
            // UISelectors.flightPageFltNum.innerHTML = flightNum;

            // CONTINUE HERE....
            // THE PROBLEM:
            // this function is trying to execute before flight.html is loaded
            // therefore the element i am trying to console.log() is returning null
            // i need to find a way to use async js to wait for the page to be loaded
            // before i can execute below code.
            console.log(UISelectors.flightPageFltNum.nodeName);
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You will have to provide a lot more context here.  What is `UISelectors.flightPageFltNum` and where does it come from?  You will need some sort of event you can hook into that tells you when that page is loaded or when the `.innerHTML` is ready.  `async/await` don't provide any magic to know when some asynchronous operation is done.  They just monitor a promise that is already hooked into the asynchronous operation.  So, you need something that is hooked into the asynchronous operation so you can know when it's done.

Comment: Also, when a user clicks on a link and that link they clicked on starts to load, it replaces the content of your current page entirely (unless it's configured to open in a new window) so the current page's Javascript is no longer around to participate in the new page loading at all.  The code you want to run would need to be in that other page or the new page would have to be loaded in a new window and of the same origin as your current page.

Comment: What do you mean by "*on another html page called flight.html*"? How (and where) is that other page loaded?

Comment: @Bergi When a link is clicked on index.html, it opens flight.html, which is located in the same folder. I've added an event listener to the click event for this link, which calls updateFlightNum(), which then calls updateFlightPage(). 

I want updateFlightNum() to pass a string from an element on the index.html page, to the updateFlightPage() function, whose job it is to display the passed string on the flight.html page.

What it boils down to, is that I want to display a string variable that I extracted from an element on index.html, as innerHTML on an element of the flight.html page.

Comment: If you navigate to a different page (it's not a popup, right?) and want to pass data, use URL parameters. Set `link.href = "flight.html?num=" + flightPageFltNum`. Then in the javascript of the newly loaded page, extract the URL parameters and display them where you want.

Comment: @bergi thank you so much for answering my question. Like I said, I am very new to JS and web dev in general, and I have now learned something new. Much appreciated.